# How to create flowtype declarations for Chai plugins

Tags: chai, flowtype

Does anyone have any idea of how I might be able to create flowtype declarations for chai plugins (or if it's at all possible)?

For example, the chai-as-promised plugin adds methods like `.rejectedWith(error)` to `chai.expect()`, so you could use it like this:

```
expect(myPromise).to.be.rejectedWith('some error message')
```

So here, I'd be looking to add a definition for `rejectedWith` to the return type of chai's `expect`.

BTW, chai itself does have flow-typed declarations (https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/chai_v3.5.x), and it looks like what's been happening so far is that they're adding such plugin declarations directly to the chai declarations.